# My highchart not showing the correct time on the x-axis

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

I have to show the real-time power consumption values in a dynamic line chart. I amusing **highcharts** library for this. I want that both the time on the x-axis and the power on the y-axis are taken from the mysql database. But even after extracting the time and power consumption value from the database properly i am not getting the correct time on the highchart.

For developing the code I made the following tables in database. I have inserted assumed values for developing the code only.

```
mysql> use sample;
Database changed
mysql> select * from Power_data;
+-------+----------+---------------------+
| SR_NO | POWER_D1 | DATE_TIME           |
+-------+----------+---------------------+
|     1 |  294.975 | 2016-02-04 06:01:00 |
|     2 |  295.837 | 2016-02-04 06:02:00 |
|     3 |   279.45 | 2016-02-04 06:03:00 |
|     4 |  288.765 | 2016-02-04 06:04:00 |
|     5 |   298.08 | 2016-02-04 06:05:00 |
|     6 |  319.297 | 2016-02-04 06:06:00 |
+-------+----------+---------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from counter
    -> ;
+-----+---------+---------+---------+
| cid | select1 | select2 | select3 |
+-----+---------+---------+---------+
|   1 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
+-----+---------+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then I wrote the code for the live server in the file live.php.
This code gives me the time correctly in the form of milliseconds as required by highcharts.

```
<?php
// Set the JSON header
header("Content-type: text/json");  

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'root';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(! $conn ) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('sample');
$sql1='SELECT select1 FROM counter WHERE cid=1';
$r=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql1,$conn));
$i=$r['select1'];
//echo $i;

$sql2='SELECT * FROM Power_data WHERE SR_NO='.$i;
$result=mysql_query($sql2,$conn);

if(!$result){
die('Could not get data:' . mysql_error());
}
$i++;
$sql3='UPDATE counter SET select1='.$i.' WHERE cid=1';
mysql_query($sql3,$conn);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
extract($row);  
$y=$POWER_D1;
$x=strtotime($DATE_TIME);
// Create a PHP array and echo it as JSON
$ret = array($x, $y);
echo json_encode($ret,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

}
 mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

After this my code which take the live data and displays it in the line charts goes like this. The file name is client.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<script type="text/javascript src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var chart;
/**
 * Request data from the server, add it to the graph and set a timeout 
 * to request again
 */
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'live.php',
        success: function(point) {
    //document.write(point);
            var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is 
                                             // longer than 20

            // add the point
           chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);

           // call it again after one second
           setTimeout(requestData, 1000);    
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
            events: {
                load: requestData
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150,
            maxZoom: 20 * 1000
        },
        yAxis: {
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            title: {
                text: 'Value',
                margin: 80
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: []
        }]
    });        
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My highchart is showing wrong values for the time on x-axis. Someone please tell if I am missing on something.

Comment: Hey, I know is not the point of the question but I recommend you using `mysqli` (stands for mysql improved) functions instead of `mysql` since the last is already deprecated. More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp

Comment: @fabionr That doesnt solve the problem as all the data is being retrieved from mysql in proper format. The problem I think is in the javascript part..

Comment: @fabionr makes a good point though. This code appears to narrowly miss SQL injection security issues by virtue of the fact that column `select1` is an integer and is not user-originated. However, if this column was a user-originated string (e.g. a username) then `$sql2` would be vulnerable. Since this database extension is deprecated, it is worth moving to a better alternative: PDO/mysql or mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your line:

```
$x=strtotime($DATE_TIME);
```

To:

```
$x=strtotime($DATE_TIME)*1000;
```

Highcharts `datetime` series expects x-values in the form of timestamps in **milliseconds**. PHPs `strtotime` returns a timestamp in **seconds**.

Comment: I made that change you said. And I am still getting the wrong time on x-axis. I checked and found out that the timestamp coming to highcharts is correct. but it is not interpreting the timestamp right while displaying.

Comment: Well you'd have to describe what you are actually seeing then. What does "not interpreting it right" mean? How big is the difference between expected and shown? Is it just the timezone offset?

Comment: Yess I finally got it right. It was actually the timezone offset which was giving the wrong time on the x-axis. I added this code:  Highcharts.setOptions({
global: {
    useUTC: false
}
});   Now It works properly..